# JPA 2.1: can't get access to the database

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa

guys!
After rebuilding my previously working web project I've faced a problem: can't reach a database with working before config. I tried to reach DB through the main method, however, the result is the same. I have a few backups of my project and all of them can't receive access to the DB.
In persistence.xml I've tried to mention complete path for DB, but there is no effect (previously this config works fine).
Unfortunately, no exception is thrown, thus I can't find where the problem is.

Configuration: JPA 2.1, JDK 1.8.0_60, Maven, Spring 4.1

I would be grateful for any advice how to trace and fix the issue.

My persistence.xml (schemes declarations are ignored):

```
<persistence-unit name="Restaurant" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>
             org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
        </provider>
    <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:..//RestaurantDB1;create=true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static" />

    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

My .log snippet:

```
    22:27:13.425 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
22:27:13.426 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
22:27:13.426 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
22:27:13.426 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
22:27:13.426 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor'
22:27:13.426 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
22:27:13.427 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
22:27:13.427 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'transactionManager'
22:27:13.437 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'transactionManager' to allow for resolving potential circular references
22:27:13.451 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
22:27:13.452 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'transactionManager'
22:27:13.454 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
22:27:13.455 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'transactionManager'
22:27:13.455 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0'
22:27:13.455 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
22:27:13.455 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator'
22:27:13.455 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0'
22:27:13.455 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0'
22:27:13.455 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
22:27:13.455 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
22:27:13.456 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
22:27:13.458 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@2611b9a3]
22:27:13.459 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
22:27:13.462 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
22:27:13.463 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
22:27:13.463 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
22:27:13.463 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'superUserServiceImpl'
22:27:13.756 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler - Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
[EL Info]: 2015-12-19 22:27:13.781--ServerSession(579294521)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b
[EL Config]: connection: 2015-12-19 22:27:13.791--ServerSession(579294521)--Connection(2109219177)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>DerbyPlatform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>null
))
22:27:13.792 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:derby:..//RestaurantDB1;create=true]
[EL Config]: connection: 2015-12-19 22:27:14.889--ServerSession(579294521)--Connection(2048102341)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:derby:..//RestaurantDB1
    User: APP
    Database: Apache Derby  Version: 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
    Driver: Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver  Version: 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
[EL Config]: connection: 2015-12-19 22:27:14.891--ServerSession(579294521)--Connection(932885627)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>DerbyPlatform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>null
))
22:27:14.891 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:derby:..//RestaurantDB1;create=true]
[EL Config]: connection: 2015-12-19 22:27:14.897--ServerSession(579294521)--Connection(1313799195)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:derby:..//RestaurantDB1
    User: APP
    Database: Apache Derby  Version: 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
    Driver: Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver  Version: 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
[EL Info]: connection: 2015-12-19 22:27:14.989--ServerSession(579294521)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--file:/D:/Підготовка до Канади/Джава/Java EE/project/DAily backup/ElectronicRestaurant/target/classes_Restaurant login successful
22:27:15.022 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:derby:..//RestaurantDB1;create=true]
22:27:15.145 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:derby:..//RestaurantDB1;create=true]
22:27:15.169 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:derby:..//RestaurantDB1;create=true]
22:27:15.197 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:derby:..//RestaurantDB1;create=true]
22:27:15.218 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:derby:..//RestaurantDB1;create=true]
22:27:15.300 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:derby:..//RestaurantDB1;create=true]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-12-19 22:27:15.304--ServerSession(579294521)--Connection(456785282)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT ID, DATEOFBIRTH, DATEOFCREATION, DATEOFLASTLOGIN, DELIVERYADDRESS, EMAIL, ISACTIVE, LOGIN, NAME, PASSWORD, SURNAME, TYPEOFUSER FROM USERS WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [7]
22:27:15.323 [main]      DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
null
```

Some dependencies:

```
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-agent</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSR-330 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- EL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.10.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.10.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: And what does "can't reach" and "is not working" exactly mean? What error messages do you get? What do you expect to happen? The logfile which you posted looks good, there doesn't seem to be any error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem was that in spite of the full DB path, an application couldn't reach it. It turned out that I have 3(!) various data source paths: one is in persistence.xml, another - in application-config.xml, and the last one - in beans.xml. I consider this approach not to be a correct one, but where the unique datasource path should be mentioned in web-application?

Comment: That depends on how you want to initialize the db connection. If you use a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, you don't need the persistence.xml file, since you can specify all configurations in your bean definition. I don't know, what your application-config.xml file is, but i think the database configuration in the beans.xml file should be enough.